# UIHostingController doesn't update its size properly properly

Tags: swiftui, uihostingcontroller

I am using UIHostingController in one of the apps I'm working on and I have a problem. The embedded SwiftUI View changes its' height dynamically, but I can't seem to get the grasp on how to update it in the view it is embedded in.

The problem doesn't seem to be in the implementation as even the most basic one has this issue.

The UIView is written like this:

```
    
    var hostingController = UIHostingController(rootView: GrowingView())
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        prepareHostingController()
    }
    
    func prepareHostingController() {
        
        view.addSubview(hostingController.view)
        hostingController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            hostingController.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            hostingController.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            hostingController.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 100)
        ])
        
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    }
    
}
```

and the SwiftUI View is like this:

```
struct GrowingView: View {
    @State var height: CGFloat = 100
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: tap) {
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(.red)
                .frame(height: height)
        }
    }
    
    func tap() {
        height = 200
    }
}
```

Is there anything obvious I'm missing or is this just the behaviour of the UIHostingController which I can do nothing about? It seems like the latter shouldn't be the case.

Answer (score 2):

You should add

```swift
hostingController.sizingOptions = .intrinsicContentSize
```

to the beginning of `prepareHostingController`

Comment: Nice, this helped me, but it's only available for iOS 16 and up. Now I need a solution for iOS 15.

Comment: Anyone know an equivalent solution for iOS 15?